# Google Cloud Firebase platform: Cloud function is not working in several of our projects today, any service down today?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We have several mobile web apps (the same code, some are dev and some in production stage) that are using Google Firebase Cloud Function service for a while. They have been working good in the past several months.

Today, during my testing, I found one bot that does not use Firebase Cloud Function is working the same way as before, but other copies of the same app that used Firebase Cloud Function are not working. Based on this page below, Firebase Cloud Function product is working today.
https://status.firebase.google.com

Any advice and suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you have concerns about the availability of Firebase, Stack Overflow is not the first best place to ask.  Please contact Firebase support directly with any problems you may be encountering. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for this note. The Firebase users are encouraged to post all Q and problems here. I will try the above page.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question not a programming question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking